# DAX Measure to Calculate Percentage of Customers with New Purchases Within One Year Sliding Window

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure that will give me the percentage of customers during a calendar year who had new purchases within one year of their last purchase.

Normally I would just create a calculated column that captured the date of each customer's last purchase for each year, and then check to see if each customer from a given year had any purchases within a year of their respective last date, and then sum those up, but I'm using a live connection to a cube and can't create calculated columns.

Here's some pseudo-code of what I'm looking for:

```
One Year Return =
VAR Cohort =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Customer[ID],
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Sales[Sales Date] ),
        YEAR ( Sales[Sales Date] )
            < ( YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1 )
    )
)
VAR Returners =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Customer[ID],
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Sales[Sales Date] ),
        Sales[Sales Date] > Sales[Old Sales Date]  //<--Need help here 
    ),
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( Customer[ID] ),
        Customer[ID] IN Cohort
    )
)
VAR Rate =
CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Customer[ID] ), Customer[ID] IN Returners ) /
CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Customer[ID] ), Customer[ID] IN Cohort )
RETURN
    Rate
```

The main difficulty is that I need a different time window for each customer, but can't make a calculated column. I've been looking at using EARLIER or DATESBETWEEN or PARALLELPERIOD, but haven't been able to get any of them to work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing a dataset from the cube and creating calculated columns to get me there after all. @jelle-hoekstra's answer looks close to what I ended up doing, but I couldn't figure out how to get his measure to run.

I made three calculated columns and did a distinct count on the ReturnCustomerID column to get the number of customers who returned within one year of their last purchase:

```
Last Purchase Date = 
MINX (
    FILTER (
        Sales,
        Sales[Sales Year]+1 = EARLIER ( Sales[Sales Year] ) &&  Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Sales[CustomerID] )
    ), 
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            Sales,
            Sales[Sales Year] = EARLIER ( Sales[Sales Year] ) && Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Sales[CustomerID] )
        ),
        Sales[Sales Date]
    )
)


One Year Date = 
MINX (
    FILTER (
        Sales,
        Sales[Sales Year]+1 = EARLIER ( Sales[Sales Year] ) && Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Sales[CustomerID] )
    ), 
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            Sales,
            Sales[Sales Year] = EARLIER ( Sales[Sales Year] ) && Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER ( Sales[CustomerID] )
        ), 
        EDATE (Sales[Sales Date], 12 )
    )
)


ReturnCustomerID = 
IF (
    Sales[Sales Date] > Sales[Last Purchase Date] && Sales[Sales Date] < Sales[One Year Date], Sales[CustomerID], BLANK()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First I think you are looking for this

```
VAR last_year = DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1; MONTH ( TODAY () ); DAY ( TODAY () ) )
```

Second. The best way to get this done you need a bit of data modeling. The only way to make time intelligence work is to have a Date table. This table should have a row by day without missing days. You can search online how to create one or check my blog [here](https://blog.ladataweb.com.ar/post/185012464051/data-modeling-como-hago-una-tabla-fecha).
Once you have this table releated on your model with your fact table you will be able to build that measure on a selected date. The selected one will be a value and last year of selected value the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The crux is in the fact that you need to compare for each customer without a calculated column. It is possible by using the an iterator like COUNTX or SUMX. This enables you to loop through your customers in the cohort sub-table and create selections of your sales table by using the customer ID in the current iteration to filter your sales table using EARLIER. For each customer in the cohort you then select their last purchase date and the one before that and compare the two to see if they followed within the year.

In DAX it looks a bit complex but I tried to make it spacier so it is easier to follow. It also contains a little workaround for the fact that you cannot simply loop over the _cohort variable as you won't have access to the customer ID in the current iteration in that case

```
One year return = 
    var _now = TODAY()

    var _cohort = 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            Sales[CustomerID] ;
            FILTER ( 
                Sales ; 
                DATEDIFF( Sales[SalesDate] ; _now ; YEAR ) <= 1 
            )
        )

    var _countCohort = COUNTROWS( _cohort )

    var _countReturns =
        SUMX (
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                Sales[CustomerID] ; FILTER ( Sales ; Sales[CustomerID] IN _cohort )
            ) ; 
            var _lastPurchase = 
                CALCULATE ( 
                    MAX ( Sales[SalesDate] ) ;
                    ALLSELECTED ( Sales ) ;
                    Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER( Sales[CustomerID] )
                )
            var _preLastPurchase = 
                CALCULATE ( 
                    MAX ( Sales[SalesDate] ) ;
                    ALLSELECTED ( Sales ) ;
                    Sales[SalesDate] < _lastPurchase ;
                    Sales[CustomerID] = EARLIER( Sales[CustomerID] )
                )
            RETURN
                IF ( DATEDIFF( _preLastPurchase ; _lastPurchase ; YEAR ) <= 1 ; 1 ; 0 )
        )


RETURN
    _countReturns / _countCohort
```